# Many point compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $X$ is a noncompact LCH space (locally compact, Hausdorff) then its one point compactification is $X^*=X\cup \{\infty\}$ with topology $\mathcal{T^*}$ given by $U \in \mathcal{T^*}$ iff either

a) $U \subset X$ is open, or

b) if $\infty \in U$ then $U^c \subset X$ is compact

What whould be the definition and the topology for 2 point compactification, or 4 point compactification. Like in $\mathbb{R^2}$ where there are 4 infinities: $\pm \infty$ on $x$ axis and $\pm \infty$ on $y$ axis?

Answer (score 7):

For $n>1$ the space $\Bbb R^n$ has a one-point compactification, but it does not have a $k$-point compactification for any integer $k>1$; see [this PDF](http://susanjkleinart.com/compactification/Wsr5.pdf). $\Bbb R$ itself has both a one-point compactification, which is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$, and a two-point compactification, which is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

You might also want to look at the notion of an [*end*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_%28topology%29) in topology.

Comment: that follows from the fact that $\beta \mathbb R ^n\setminus \mathbb R ^n$ is connected, for $n>1$, right? (so the only finite set it can map onto is a singleton).

Comment: @ForeverMozart: I hadn’t thought of it in those terms, but yes, that sounds right.

Comment: yes because the remainder is an intersection of connected sets, because the complement of any compact subset of $\mathbb R ^n$, $n>1$, is connected... no thats not true.  But we could look at complements of balls only...like $\beta \mathbb R ^n \setminus \mathbb R ^n=\bigcap _{n\in\mathbb N} \text{cl}_{\beta\mathbb R ^n} \mathbb R ^n \setminus B(0,n)$

Comment: It doesn't have _any_ four-point compactifications? Or just no Hausdorff ones?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I'll have to think about that.  My intuition says you can't even get $T_0$.

Comment: fwiw, I should have used a different index than $n$ in the intersection above...

Comment: @ForeverMozart What about $\Bbb R^2\cup\{(0,\infty),(0,-\infty),(\infty,0),(-\infty,0)\}$ where a neighborhood of $(0,\infty)$ is any set containing $(\Bbb R\times{]a,\infty[})\cup(0,\infty)$ for some $a$ (and similarly for the other infinities)? Using the notation $]a,b[$ for open intervals to avoid confusion with points.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ah, yes that gets $T_0$ I think.  Good.  Might want to check the details. Might want $a>0$. Then use $-a$ for the neighborhood of $(0,-\infty)$, etc.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Would that change anything? Let $U_a:=(\Bbb R\times{]a,\infty[})\cup(0,\infty)$ ($U$ for "upper"). Then, even if $a<0$, we have $U_a\supseteq U_1$ and is thus a neighborhood. The neighborhoods of $(0,-\infty)$ would be $L_a:=(\Bbb R\times{]-\infty,a[})\cup(0,-\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

$R$ has a $1$-point and a $2$-point compactification but not an $n$-point comp... for finite $n>2.$ (This was a problem in AMM some decades ago.) The space $\omega_1$ with the $\epsilon$-order topology has, up to equivalence, only 1 comp... namely, the identity embedding into $\omega_1+1.$ It may be useful in some algebraic contexts to have just 4 infinities for the real plane, on the axes, but topologically the line $y=x$ is going to be confused about which of these it should "go to".