# N-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty_1,..., \infty_n\} $ be a topological space in which the topology is: the neighborhood of $\infty_i$ are $A \cup \infty_i$ with $A^c$ a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. The problem asks to find the fundamental group of X. I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance for every hint\answer.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1638310/192336. The paper referred to there is: Magill Jr, K. D. "N-point compactifications." The American Mathematical Monthly 72.10 (1965): 1075-1081.

Comment: I guess that what they wanted to say is that doesn't exist an hausdorff n point compactification for n>1 . I'm including also the non-hausdorff case.. does it makes sense? It comes from a test, so I think it does have some sense.

Comment: @Moya: That's not really related; the compactification discussed here is not Hausdorff, and indeed is just the 1-point compactification with multiple "copies" of the point at $\infty$, as in the line with doubled origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually $\mathbb R$ does have an obvious 2-point Hausdorff compactification, (not for any larger n though), but the compactification defined in your problem is different and definitely not Hausdorff.

Think of it as bending $\mathbb R$ round into a circle with one point missing, but then putting n points into the gap. They are distinct but have the same neighbourhoods within $\mathbb R$. A path going round the circle can pass through different infinities, but only one on each circuit. A loop which goes through one infinity but then comes back through another will not be homotopic to the null loop so the fundamental group is not the same as that of a circle. See if you can work it out from there.

Comment: So it should be the free product of n copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. But why every loop can pass through just one infinte "at time"?

Comment: Suppose a path $f$ does pass directly between two infinity points. Then there must be a and b such that $f(a) = \infty_i , f(b) = \infty_j$ and every point between a and b maps to one or the other infinity. But then the interval $[a,b]$ maps onto $\{\infty_i, \infty_j\} $which is not possible as the continuous image of a connected subset must be connected.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This is actually completely straightforward with van Kampen's theorem.  What are some simple open sets you could use to cover $X$, which let you ignore the non-Hausdorff weirdness when looking at just one of the open sets at a time?

A stronger hint is hidden below.

> Cover $X$ with the open sets $U_i=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty_i\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.  Each $U_i$ is just an ordinary 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a circle.

Comment: So, you're saying that the fundamental group is $ \mathbb{Z} ^{*n} $? (If I remember well how to use van Kampfen)

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb{R}$ only has a one-point and two-point compactfication (homeomorphic to $S^1$ resp. $[0,1]$)

$\mathbb{R}^n$ has just a one-point compactification, not an $m$-point one for $m>1$: consider the intersection of the complements of the open balls $B(0,n)$ in such a compactification: it's an intersection of compact and connected (!) sets hence compact and connected and so cannot be a finite $m$-point set.

Comment: This is a good answer to a totally different question than the one asked here.

Comment: @EricWofsey IMHO computing the fundamental group of such a non-Hausdorff space is a bit silly/artificial.

Comment: You might add that it's also a nested intersection since otherwise the result doesn't have to be connected.